# How to split the large HAML template

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have very large HAML template. I'm just wondering if there is any possibility to split it into separate HAML-files and include them into original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#implementation_of_rails_style_partials

Answer (score 1):

Note that as of Sinatra 1.1 [you no longer need a "partial" helper](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/CHANGES#L443), as the `haml` method will automatically detect if you are calling it from within a template and add the `layout:false` option accordingly.

---

I use a helper method that is more powerful than the simple implementation linked to by @Nash, but simpler than the 'full' method they include there:

```
def partial( page, variables={} )
  haml page, {layout:false}, variables
end
```

Use it like so:

```
#comment= partial :comment, user:@user, comment:@comment
```

This is part of my [Riblits](https://github.com/Phrogz/riblits) shell for new Sinatra projects, easily usable by [Monk](http://rubygems.org/gems/monk) like so:

```sh
# Before creating your project
monk add riblits git://github.com/Phrogz/riblits.git

# Inside your empty project directory
monk init -s riblits
```